# One JS file for every single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods

I have a huge JS file for my entire my Web Project (Main.js). (Now I don't want you to compare these approaches to keep and use JS/CSS files (One huge or mutiple).
Now my question: So, there are some scripts which are for some pages, some are not. as excepted, I want don't want all of the scripts (which are in $(documents).ready(function () { }) to be executed in all of my pages.
to handle this, I made my approach and that is:
in my JS file I have one function for each page (SignUp page: function signUp() etc.)
and in each page, I call the function of the page in `<script>` tag.
am I doing right?

Answer (score 0):

> am I doing right?

IMHO No. Separate the code into individual JS files and only load the JS file that applies to a given HTML page with that HTML file. Put common JS code into a `common.js` file and load that in all pages.